# Leveraging Salesforce Authentication

Tags: apex, authentication

I'm looking to leverage Salesforce Authentication for my website. Essentially I'd like the user to be able to enter their username/password, have that validated by Salesforce, and then be able to query their information to display it on my site.

Is that possible through Salesforce? What tools would I use to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking this in context to Single Sign-On capabilities?

Comment: @JayantDas I think that would be appropriate!

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Salesforce as Identity Provider (IdP).

Refer [Enable Salesforce as an Identity Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&type=5)

> Salesforce can act as a single sign-on (SSO) identity provider to service providers, allowing end users to easily and securely access many web and mobile applications with one login. When using SAML for federated authentication, enable Salesforce as an identity provider and then set up connected apps. However, the OpenID Connect protocol for SSO authentication doesn’t require enabling Salesforce as an identity provider.

After you enable Salesforce as an identity provider, you can create connected apps to provide access to service providers.

Here is a flow:

[image: Salesforce as IdP]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to setup Salesforce as an Identity Provider (IdP). You can definitely use Salesforce as IdP.

> Salesforce can act as a single sign-on (SSO) identity provider to service providers, allowing end users to easily and securely access many web and mobile applications with one login

You can find more details on this subject on the official documentation as how you can utilize Salesforce to be setup as IdP.

- [Enable Salesforce as an Identity Provider](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_enable.htm&type=5)